# How to make separate versions of code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

There isn't any "Save as" or similars. How can I have separate versions of my project?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain more so that others can help you easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood the question, one usually uses version control tools for that; for instance, Git.
There is a git plugin for Android Studio if you want to manage different versions of your project on different branches.